# PHP-Read Receipt

Tags: php, email, email-headers

I have a contact form where you specify the contact Information along with your  email id. Once the form is sent it comes to my Inbox. The mail specifies the Information supplied by the user. I would like the sender of the contact form to receive a read receipt once I open the email.

This is what I have done so far

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email'];
    $subject='Contact Form Replies';
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $message=$_POST['msg'];
    $body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
    "Email: $email_address\n Phone Number: $phone \n Message: $message \n ";


    $headers = 'From: ' .$email_address. ''.
$headers .= 'X-Confirm-Reading-To: '.$email_address. '';



    mail('xyz@gmail.com', $subject, $body,$headers))




?>
```

Now as per this code the mail gets successfully delivered to my Inbox. But once I open the mail, the read receipt does not go to the sender. Kindly advice on how I can overcome this Issue

Comment: This can be done, but it won't be done simply. The sending server has no way of knowing an email was opened, you're going to need hook into your email client or create your own email client or set up your own mail server.

Comment: I would advise you use a service like mailgun (thousands of emails free per month) which will allow you to track this through a simple API

Answer (score 0):

Most email (web) clients disable any ability for the sender to check if an email is opened. They disable JavaScript, disable external sources so this is only possible with a own email server where users all use the same software such as outlook to have a reliable result.

However one possible way is to add an HTML image linking to `image.php?receit=1234` and let that load up a php script that returns a tracking pixel. Now you know the email is opened and the user clicked the button to show all images.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can get started doing that. Any links to relevant blogs or tutorials would be appreciated.